# Is it possible to set a reference to an AsyncTask to null in onPostExecute()?

Tags: android, garbage-collection, android-asynctask

I have an Activity class which has an attribute that references an AsyncTask instance and this AsyncTask also has a reference to this Activity.

**From the AsyncTask's `onPostExecute()` I want to set the reference from the Activity to the AsyncTask to null** (through the reference that has the AsyncTask instance to the Activity). Is it a good practice?

I am doing it at the last line of code of the method, because I am actually saying to the garbage collector that it can delete that instance as it is no longer referenced by any other object (the Activity). Is it correct, or am I wrong?

**Edit:** My answer below resumes the final solution I used.

Thanks!

Comment: any particular reason why you feel that it's necessary to do this? it looks probably safe, but there's always the risk of something weird happening with multithreading, and it seems unnecessary in most cases

Comment: Yes, I agree with you mfrankli, I know this can be troubleshooting. However, I need to know when the AsyncTask finishes and I also need to keep the reference to the AsyncTask while it is running, because I am recycling it in rotation changes (see my comment on @SawasDalkitsis' answer). I thought this would be the best place to set it to null, but I am not sure about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to keep the reference to the AsyncTask in the first place?

When is the reference no longer needed? What happens before the task has finished that requires you to hold a reference to the activity?

What I am saying is, you can start the async task without a reference to it so your problem goes away. But if for some reason you do need the reference, then by explaining your particular case more, we can suggest a better solution.

**EDIT**

Your main concern is not leaking the activity, not the other way around. If you really want to clean up all references properly, I would provide an attach/detach method on the async task so that activities can attach and detach themselves from the async task when nessecary and also provide a method on the activity that nullifies the async task refence and call that from your async task if an activity is still attached. Do not do it directly. The async task should not modify the activity directly. If possible even move the async task in a new file, don't  make it an internal class of the activity, that screams of leaks.

Comment: I need the reference in the Activity to "recycle" the AsyncTask in a rotation change, to avoid recreating the asynctask instance each time. E.g. while downloading data from a server, if the device is rotated I want the same AsyncTask, not to start a new one. So, I control this using `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`. But I want to set the reference to null once the AsyncTask finishes, so I am trying to do it in `onPostExecute()`. Thanks! :)

Comment: why not simply set the reference to null onstop or onpause? there is no harm in keeping that reference around until your activity finishes.

Comment: I need the reference to the Activity from the AsyncTask as I am accesing the SQLiteDatabase and I need a Context , so I pass the Activity itself. Once the AsyncTask finishes I know all data has been downloaded from server and I would like to set that reference to null to free that task, as it is no longer needed and I do not want to recycle it anymore. What you say about `attach()` I already do so in the `onCreate()` of the Activity if the reference to the AsyncTask is not null, so the old Activity can be garbage collected. The AsyncTask class is static, so there would not be problems there.

Comment: If the only reason you need a context is a database access (non UI work), consider passing in the application context and thus freeing the dependency between the async task and the activity.

Comment: If you also need the activity reference to update any UI after the operation has completed, use the attach detach mechanism. it's not a good idea to keep an activity reference around and expect the old reference to be cleared by a new call to onCreate. what happens if no new activities are launched? if you press the home button for instance, no new activity will come in to replace the old in the async task. You've now leaked the activity.

Comment: for an even more separated solution (which is a good thing), you can update UI elements by broadcasting results from your async task. Each activity can register itself as a receiver.

Comment: and as a last suggestion, have you looked into Loaders? They are Honeycomb and newer APIs but can be used in older versions with the compatibility library. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your attention! :) I need the Activity reference to update UI elements appart from db access, so I need it. Also, I need the reference from Activity to task in order to recycle it. I do not use detach() because the task is supposed to run even if the activity is destroyed, in that case, if the activity was detached I guess the task would raise a NullPointerException in `onProgressUpdate()` or `onPostExecute()` as it's reference will no longer exist. Am I wrong here? But as you state, I would leak an Activity here, which is not good...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9130/discussion-between-caumons-and-savvas-dalkitsis)

Answer (score 4):

After a great discussion with @SavvasDalkitsis see [his answer and the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9796656/955619) I came up with an answer that satisfies my requirements. I wanted to set to null the AsyncTask once it finished for two reasons:

1. To know if it had finished
2. To do not recycle it anymore as it is no needed once it has been executed once

There is actually no need to set an AsyncTask to null once it has finished (if using the correct approach of attaching the new activity on a rotation change to avoid memory leaks) to know it has finished. Instead, we can check its status. This way we know if it has already finished or not. Then, in the `onCreate()` after calling `getLastNonConfigurationChange()` method we can also check this and set it to null if finished, to do not recycle it anymore:

```
if (mTask == null || mTask.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)) {
    mTask = null;
} else {
    mTask.attach(this);
}
```

Hope this helps somebody else! :)

Comment: not that it matters much but since i provided the correct answer you might want to accept my answer instead of yours :P